# Breaking down %5d%*.*f format specifier in C for precise output formatting

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, printf

I'm working with formatted output in C and encountered the format string `%5d%*.*f`. While I understand the basic use of `%d` for integers and `%f` for floating-point numbers, I'm specifically seeking clarification on:

`%5d`

- What does the 5 in %5d signify?
- How does it control the output formatting of integers?

`%*.*f`

- What's the purpose of using two asterisks `(*)` in `%*.*f`?
- How do those asterisks interact with the arguments passed to `printf`?
- What level of control do they offer over floating-point output formatting?

I'm using a C compiler that adheres to the C11 standard.

Here's a code snippet illustrating my use of the format string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int val =10;
    float val1 = 56.40;
    printf("%d%*.*f", val,val,val-8,val1);
    
}
```

output is 10    56.40

what is actual menaing of `%5d%*.*f`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int val =10;
    float val1 = 56.40;
    printf("%d%f", val,val,val-8,val1);
    
}
```

output is 100.000000

why output is getting different by just outting `%d%f` ?

[Code containing %d%f code, which giving output as 100.0000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPYnr.png)

[Code containing %d%*.*f code, which giving output as 10    56.40](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST2gD.png)

Comment: Also, separating the format specifiers like `%d %f` will definitely help understand the *undefined behavior* you get in the second example, where you pass an `int` argument for the `%f` specifier (which expects a `double` value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `%5d` means print an `int` with a minimum field width of 5.  The the value isn't 5 characters wide it will be left padded with space.  You either can't tell or you didn't paste in the spaces in your example output.
- `%*.*f` means print a `float` with a minimum field width and precision (digits after the `.`) provided as arguments as signified by the `*`.  In this case field width is `val` and precision `val-8`.

Your 2nd code sample is simply incorrect usage.  You claim to pass a int and float but pass in 3 int and a float.